# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<NewUser> above this UpdateSupervisor Widget

Tags: flutter, provider

How to wrap the stream provider in onPressed function? This is my class.

UpdateSupervisor class

```
import 'package:finalyearproject/model/NewUser.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/service/database.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/shared/Loading.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



class UpdateSupervisor extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _UpdateSupervisorState createState() => _UpdateSupervisorState();
}

class _UpdateSupervisorState extends State<UpdateSupervisor> {

  // form values
   String name;
   String email;
   String uniqueID;
   String phone;
   String id;
   
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<NewUser>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Supervisor'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.id).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return Loading();
          }
          NewUser userData = snapshot.data;
          return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    initialValue: userData.name,
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Name cannot be empty!': null,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => name = value);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email cannot be empty!': null,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => email = value);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Number Phone',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Number Phone cannot be empty!': null,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => phone = value);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Unique ID ',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Ic number cannot be empty!': null,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => uniqueID = value);
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      textColor: Colors.black,
                      child: Text("Update"),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){

                          _formKey.currentState.save();
                        } else {
                          print("Validator are correct!");
                        }
                      }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      )
    );

  }
}
```

HomeSupervisor class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/model/NewUser.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/screen/crud/UpdateSupervisor.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/screen/crud/AddSupervisor.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/service/database.dart';
import 'package:finalyearproject/sidebar/AdminDrawer.dart';


class HomeSupervisor extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        title: Text('Supervisor'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddSupervisor()));
              })
        ],
      ),
      drawer: AdminDrawer(),
      body: ListSupervisor(),
    );
  }

}

class ListSupervisor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListSupervisorState createState() => _ListSupervisorState();
}

class _ListSupervisorState extends State<ListSupervisor> {
  NewUser user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: DatabaseService().getPost(),
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                          title: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].data["name"]),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].data["email"]),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].data["uniqueID"]),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  onPressed: (){

                                  }
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UpdateSupervisor()));  //here the line error show//
                                  }
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                  onPressed: () {

                                  }
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Then the erorr show that, in line 96:101 where Iconbutton which i nagivator.push to the UpdateSupervisor.
So my question is how to wrap the stream provider in onPressed()?

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this UpdateSupervisor Widget

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this UpdateSupervisor Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues
**The relevant error-causing widget was:
UpdateSupervisor file:///D:/Android_project/finalyearproject/lib/screen/home/HomeSupervisor.dart:96:101**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap MaterialApp with provider like this.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<NewUser>(create: (context) => NewUser(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home:Home(),
      ),
    );
```

additionally:
I am using ***ChangeNotifierProvider*** because I assume your provider is extending ***ChangeNotifier***.

If you are not extending ***ChangeNotifier*** You can use basic form of provider which is following:

```
Provider<NewUser>(
  create: (context) => NewUser(),
  child: child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home:Home(),
      ),
)
```

which will give you pssibility to use your ***NewUser*** object as an dependency injection for all the Provider descendent classes like this:

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget buid(BuildContext context){
    final provider = Provider.of<NewUser>(contextm, listen:false); /// you can to not set listen on false it does not matter in this case cause this type of provider is just an injection
    return Text(provider.someText);

   }
}
```

There is also ***StreamProvider*** which let's you listen on stream and update the ***Widget*** which injects this provider when the stream will receive data, check it out too.

Also there is a ***MultiProvider*** which let's you wrap MaterialApp with multiple Providers.

And also Check this [url](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) too

example of ***MultiProvider*** from [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartModel()),
        Provider(create: (context) => SomeOtherClass()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: if I my provider are not extending with changeNotifier? or should I need to extends?

Comment: there are couple of type of providers, which depends on your case of usage, 
if you want to, update some widget while the data of the provider changes it should be extending changenotifier

Comment: otherwise you can use something like this: Provider(create: (context) => SomeOtherClass())

Comment: how to write the coding streamprovider? is that same coding with mutliprovider?

Comment: if i want to use mutliprovider, it must declare the main class right? for my case, i notice that, it involve many widget.